# Are Event Objects still created for empty actionListeners (java)?

Tags: java, events, listener

I'm looking for some more information on the way that Event objects work.

My understanding is that (in java), typical event handling goes like this:

-Listener is added to the event source (i.e. added to a button)

-User interacts with the event source (i.e. clicking)

-The event source instantiates an event object containing information

-The event source passes the object into the listener, and then the listener excutes the code.

So the question is, does an event object still get created when there is no code inside the listener? i.e.

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
//Nothing here
}
```

I'm sadly unable to find a good resource to read of event interactions.

Comment: Yes. The source object can't know whether the specific method is empty or not. If you add a listener, an event is created and dispatched, even if your handler does nothing.

Comment: What you are asking comes down to: "does the result have an impact on the cause"? no, it doesn't. just because an event remains 'unhandled', from point of view of a user, doesn't mean it isn't handled by the JVM.